# CRM2011 - "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am what you call a "n00b" in CRM plugin development. I am trying to write a plugin for Microsoft's Dynamics CRM 2011 that will create a new activity entity when you create a new contact. I want this activity entity to be associated with the contact entity.

This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

namespace ITPH_CRM_Deactivate_Account_SSP_Disable
{
    public class SSPDisable_Plugin: IPlugin
    {

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["target"] is Entity)
            {
                Entity entity = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;

            if (entity.LogicalName != "account")
            {
                return;
            }

            Entity followup = new Entity();
            followup.LogicalName = "activitypointer";
            followup.Attributes = new AttributeCollection();
            followup.Attributes.Add("subject", "Created via Plugin.");
            followup.Attributes.Add("description", "This is generated by the magic of C# ...");
            followup.Attributes.Add("scheduledstart", DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));
            followup.Attributes.Add("actualend", DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));

            if (context.OutputParameters.Contains("id"))
            {
                Guid regardingobjectid = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
                string regardingobjectidType = "account";

                followup["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(regardingobjectidType, regardingobjectid);

            }

            service.Create(followup);

        }


    }

}
```

But when i try to run this code: I get an error when i try to create a new contact in the CRM environment. The error is: "The given key was not present in the dictionary" (Link *1). The error pops up right as i try to save the new contact.

Link *1: http://puu.sh/4SXrW.png
(Translated bold text: "Error on business process")

Comment: I think the error is with `activitypointer`, you need to specify the exact activity entity type you want to create (task, appointment, ...)

Comment: Any suggestions on how i do that? I am a beginner with CRM plugin development. All the help i can get is much appreciated.

Comment: You are saying that you want to create activity when user creates a contact but in code you are looking for "account" entity.

Comment: @Scorpion you spotted another error! @DJZorrow you need to use `task` instead of `activitypointer` for example, and change account to contact as @Scorpion wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM uses the term activity to describe several types of interactions. The types of activities are:
Phone Call, Task, E-mail, Letter, Fax and Appointment.

[ActivityPointer (Activity) Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327870.aspx)

To make your code working Replace the following line:

```
Entity followup = new Entity();
```

with

```
Entity followup = new Entity("task");
```

And remove the following line:

```
followup.LogicalName = "activitypointer";
```

Also please read my comment and  Guido Preite's commend above. You need to modify your code to make it working with contact.

**Edited**

Make sure `ContactId` does exist in CRM before referencing it to Activity.

Comment: Sorry this did not solve the problem. I still get the same error message as before. Is there any more relevant data i can provide to make it easier to spot a possible error?

Comment: Can you please confirm that plugin is registered on post or pre stage. I think context.OutputParameters["id"] is not existed in the system at the time you are trying to create Activity.

Comment: I have it on post i believe. [Add assembly](http://puu.sh/4T0du.png) [Add step](http://puu.sh/4T0fC.png)

Comment: I believe this is the solution for you, please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638152/crm-2011-post-operation-plugin-primary-entity-does-not-exist-when-attempting-t/10654835#10654835

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Scorpion and Guido! The problem has now been resolved! :)

Answer (score 0):

This can often happen if you are explicity adding an attribute value to the target entity in you plugin where it already has been added.

Rather than entity.Attributes.Add(...)

use entity["attributename"] = ...